# Coverting row data into separate columns

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
       state county   age   population
         AL  Autauga   5       2366
         AL  Autauga   1       3029
         AL  Autauga   2       3619
         AL  Autauga   7       3043
         AL  Autauga   3       3776
         AL  Autauga   15      1160
         AL  Autauga   12      2326 
         AL  Baldwin   12      8365
         AL  Baldwin   4       9537
         AL  Baldwin   8       10753
```

Which I want to convert into the following

```
      state county  age1pop age2pop age3pop age4pop age5pop age6pop...
       AL   Autauga  3029    3619    3776    0       2366     0
       AL   Baldwin    0      0       0      9537     0       0
```

I.e. I want to covert the age rows into separate columns